# How to properly select pandas rows by column condition, for calculation

Tags: python, pandas

I don't understand the behaviour of Pandas in this situation. Obviously, problem is in row 3 where column A has negative value, and this leads to math issue with trying to raise it on fractional power.

I limited the rows where I want this np.power to run by condition A>1 using df.loc. And from resulting NaN at row 0, column C, it is obvious that filter works fine, and all values in resulting dataframe are as expected, but I got error because np.power obviously still calculated row 3 for some reason.

Can you help me understand why this happens and how I can improve the code to avoid error?

```
data = [{'A': 1, 'B': 10},
         {'A': 2, 'B': 10},
         {'A': 3, 'B': 10},
         {'A': -1,  'B': 10}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
Out[4]: 
   A   B
0  1  10
1  2  10
2  3  10
3 -1  10

df['C'] = df.loc[df.A > 1, 'A'] * np.power(df['A'],0.3)
df
/home/meteoadriatic/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
Out[5]: 
   A   B         C
0  1  10       NaN
1  2  10  2.462289
2  3  10  4.171168
3 -1  10       NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
np.power(df['A'],0.3)
```

`df['A']` still refers to the whole column.

Instead, you can do it using `mul` to avoid the warning:

```
df['C'] = np.power(df.loc[df.A > 1, 'A'], 0.3).mul(df.A)

>>> df
   A   B         C
0  1  10       NaN
1  2  10  2.462289
2  3  10  4.171168
3 -1  10       NaN
```

Another option is to select again:

```
df['C'] = df.loc[df.A > 1, 'A'] * np.power(df.loc[df.A>1,'A'],0.3)
```